# Nuxt js pages shows 404 not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nodejs project created with adonuxt. I have ssl enabled in my site.

I am using nginx reverse proxy that take requests to localhost:port in my server.

There two problems.

It always shows 404 in all js file. See the image please. [image]

It also doesn't load any images.

Another problem is, I can only see some out put for the home page, but if I visit to `site.com/page` it shows 404 not found (`nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`)

Any idea whats wrong? 
Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 5):

It is caused by default Webpack settings - to change that edit your `nuxt.config.js` file to:

```
export modules = {
  buildDir: '_nuxt',
  build: {
    publicPath: '_nuxt/dist/'
  }
}
```

If you get 404 on routes check your nginx setup and make it similiar to the from the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy).

Default nginx settings does not allow vue-router to take care of routes.

Hope I helped.